# Jest testing React-Native component that used useRouter() from expo-router getting error

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, expo

I am trying to test a component that is accesing `useRouter` from [expo-router](https://expo.github.io/router/docs)

My Component:

```
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router'

const CustomComponent: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const onPress = () => {
    router.replace(PATHS.DASHBOARD)
  }

  return <HCard pressAction={onPress} title={'title'} />
}
```

The test file:

```
describe('CustomComponent', () => {
  it('should render CustomComponent correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = renderWithProvider(<CustomComponent />)
    expect(wrapper.getByText('title')).toBeOnTheScreen()
  })
})
```

I am getting this error: **Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?**

I understand what the error suggests, but I do not know how to provide that NavigationContainer, since it is not part of expo-router.
Also, I have mocked the useRouter, but got the same error

*Later edit*
Here is the renderWithProvider:

```
export const renderWithProvider = (children: JSX.Element): RenderResult => {
  const inset = {
    frame: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 },
    insets: { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
  }

  return render(<NativeBaseProvider initialWindowMetrics={inset}>{children}</NativeBaseProvider>)
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `renderWithProvider` function does not have the `NavigationContainer` as mentioned in the error

Comment: Yes, that's correct... but I don't see any NavigationContainer in expo-router, so I do not know where to take it from. That renderWithProvider it's just a Wrapper with NativeBaseProvider (edit the description and added it there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built this util to help me with this error.
Basically when you are mounting your component inside a jest suite, it doesn't have the navigation stack necessary for `useRouter` to work.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

type NavigationMockProps = {
  controller: ComponentType<any>;
  params?: any;
};
export const NavigationMock = ({ controller, params }: NavigationMockProps) => {
  const stack = createNativeStackNavigator<any>();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent>
      <stack.Navigator initialRouteName="TestRoute">
        <stack.Screen
          name="TestRoute"
          component={controller}
          initialParams={params}
          options={{ header: () => null }}
        />
      </stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
describe('CustomComponent', () => {
  it('should render CustomComponent correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = render(
       <NavigationMock controller={CustomComponent} params={params} />
    );
    expect(wrapper.getByText('title')).toBeOnTheScreen();
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Roberto, but I am not using "@react-navigation/native".

I am using **expo-router**. My application does not have `react-navigation` installed

Comment: expo router is build on top of react-navigation. So that's why it is asking for. If you check dependencies for expo router you'll see react navigation is included

Comment: Oh, yeah. You right here - I can find it there. Thanks